# JQuery don't work in one case and another work

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I'm writing a simple calculator, using JQuery.

I need to write to the input tag an error message if the user writes an invalid symbol.

And the problem is that console.log works and "$('#input')" doesn't work.
`

```
function addChar(ch) {
    num1 = $('#input').val();
    if(isNaN(num1)){
        $('#input').val("Invalid input");
        console.log("Invalid input");
    }
    op = ch;
    clearAll();
}
```

I have the same part of the code, where I use it. Another factor is working. I can't imagine why

```
    case "/":
        if(num2 == 0)
            $('#input').val("arythmetic error");
        else
            $('#input').val(num1 / num2);
        break;
```

Comment: ok, i'm forgot add return
answer is close

Comment: Please add some more context to your question (if possible, prepare an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) and explain in detail what the differenc between the observed and the expected result is.

Answer (score 0):

If the input is an id then its okay to give '#input'. Otherwise simply remove the '#' symbol(if it is a tag).

```
<div>
 <label>
 </label>
</div>
```

Bind the value as innerText

```
$('label').text("arythmetic error");
```

Try this